# Why doesn't my checkboxes show up in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem that the `Size` component didn't show up on the web page. Could someone help me figure it out?

This is my file hierarchy:

```
components
    CheckBoxes
        index.js
        style.css

    Shelf
        Filter
            index.js
            style.css
```

This is my "components/Shelf/Filter/index.js":

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Size from '../../CheckBoxes/index';

class SizePart extends Component {
    availableSizes = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'ML', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'];

    createCheckboxes = () => {
        this.availableSizes.map((size) => {
            return < Size size={size}/>
        });
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div className="filters">
                <h4 className="title">Sizes:</h4>
                {this.createCheckboxes()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SizePart;
```

This is my "components/CheckBoxes/index.js" and "components/CheckBoxes/style.css":

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./style.css";

const Size = props => {
    return <div className='size'>{props.size}</div>
}

export default Size;
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
.size {
background-color: rgb(223, 220, 220);
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 22px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
font-size: 0.8em;
margin-bottom: 8px;
margin-right: 8px;
border-radius: 50%;
line-height: 35px;
text-align: center;
}

.size:hover { 
    border: 1px solid #1b1a20;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return your array.

```
createCheckboxes = () => {
    return this.availableSizes.map((size) => {
        return < Size size={size}/>
    });
}
```

Comment: Ooooops, how careless am I. Thanks for your answer! : )